# Prolog classification by giving points to classes

Tags: prolog, classification

I'm working on an knowledge system that can return a wine when a user enters a dish. My idea is to add points to every wine class depending on the input of the user and then displaying a top 3 of fitting wine classes. So for example if someone enters fish then all the red wines in the knowledge base get zero points and the white wines do get a point. If the user then enters a type of saus or vegetable ect. Wines that match this get an extra point. This will then result in a list that shows which wines (in my knowledgebase) fit best and which fits worst according to the points. Does anyone know how I could do this in prolog.

Comment: To be honest, I think you have an operational view of _how_ to solve the problem already—which means you would be fighting Prolog to do it, because Prolog wants you to tell it _what_ you want and let it figure out _how_. I would always begin a Prolog program like this by thinking about what facts I have, and how best to supply them to Prolog, and after that, start thinking about how to bring them to bear on the problem.

Comment: *What* they want is a database of relations between wines, their characteristics, and scores. How is this fighting Prolog?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I'm talking about the point allocation and scoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a database of wines and their characteristics something like this:

```
wine_color_body(chardonnay, white, light).
wine_color_body(gruener_veltliner, white, full).
wine_color_body(cabernet_franc, red, light).
wine_color_body(pinot_noir, red, medium).
wine_color_body(merlot, red, full).
```

(You will know more about wine than I do, and probably add a lot more criteria.)

Then you can formulate your scoring rules based on individual characteristics like this:

```
dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, white, _).
dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, 0) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, red, _).

dish_wine_score(beef, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, red, _).
dish_wine_score(beef, Wine, 0) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, white, _).

dish_wine_score(dessert, Wine, 2) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _, light).
dish_wine_score(dessert, Wine, 1) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _, medium).
dish_wine_score(dessert, Wine, 0) :-
    wine_color_body(Wine, _, full).
```

For example, to see what goes with fish:

```
?- dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, Score).
Wine = chardonnay,
Score = 1 ;
Wine = gruener_veltliner,
Score = 1 ;
Wine = cabernet_franc,
Score = 0 ;
Wine = pinot_noir,
Score = 0 ;
Wine = merlot,
Score = 0.
```

And then you can easily score based on a list of dishes or their properties:

```
dishes_wine_score([], _Wine, 0).
dishes_wine_score([Dish | Dishes], Wine, Score) :-
    dish_wine_score(Dish, Wine, DishScore),
    dishes_wine_score(Dishes, Wine, RestScore),
    Score is DishScore + RestScore.
```

What wine would go best with both beef and the dessert afterwards?

```
?- dishes_wine_score([beef, dessert], Wine, Score).
Wine = cabernet_franc,
Score = 3 ;
Wine = pinot_noir,
Score = 2 ;
Wine = merlot,
Score = 1 ;
Wine = chardonnay,
Score = 2 ;
Wine = gruener_veltliner,
Score = 0.
```

Once you are at this point, you just need to collect all of these answers, sort them, and find the ones with the highest score. You can do this with `bagof/3` or `findall/3` followed by `sort/2`.

Comment: Thank you Isabelle this is a great help!

Comment: Hi! the code you sent works great! I still have one question. Some wines can appear more than once with a different score if you ask the score for the wines. How can I solve this? So: dish_wine_score(fish, Wine, Score).gives cabernet_franc 3; pinot_noir 2; cabernet_franc2; merlot 0;

Comment: I showed the answers to this query in my answer, and there was no duplication there. Also, scores for fish should only be 0 or 1 with my program. You must have changed the code somehow, but I don't know how. You could open another question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Neither `bordeaux` nor `zweigelt`?